# NSubstitute mocking a NLog logger fails

Tags: testing, mocking, nlog, nsubstitute

I have a test that looks like following:

```
[Test]
public void LoggerTest()
{
    var log = Substitute.For<Logger>();
    log.DidNotReceiveWithAnyArgs().Info("");
    log.ReceivedWithAnyArgs().Info("");
}
```

The test succeeds, which it obviously shouldn't. To my best knowledge this is the syntax according to the NSubstitue website.
Can anybody tell me where the problem lies?

I use NSubstitue in version 1.7.2.0 from the NuGet package manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NLog.Logger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/59ed8c1f97bd7cbbe5c9e558b1c61757e1765c2b/src/NLog/Logger.cs#L48) is a concrete class with non-virtual members, so NSubstitute will not be able work with it (see the note on [Creating a substitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/creating-a-substitute/)).

If you need to test logging one option is to wrap the log functionality in your own, app-specific interface. This makes it easier to substitute in a new logger for testing purposes (can use NSubstitute or other mocking library, or hand-code your own `TestLogger` tailored for your test purposes).